# R as.POSIXlt error when converting a column of datetime texts

Tags: r, datetime, posix

I've got a column of text fields that are in a datetime format, which I'd like to convert to datetime objects so I can sort them sanely. I'm using `data.table`.

My column looks a little something like this:

```
Test Date
2022-01-05 04:47:05.763
NA
2022-02-16 09:51:00.000
NA
NA
2022-02-06 10:56:00.000
```

My code to convert this data.table `dt` to datetime objects is as follows (meant to handle NA values by converting them to a default datetime):

```
dt[, `Test Date` := as.POSIXlt(ifelse(is.na(`Test Date`), '2022-01-01 00:00:00', `Test Date`))]
```

My error on that line is:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(ifelse(is.na(`Test Date`), "2021-01-01 00:00:00",  : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Unsure where I'm going wrong (unsure which rows are causing the error).

Platform `x86_64-w64-mingw32`, R `4.1.2` using RStudio

Comment: perhaps try to supply `format` and `tz`: `as.POSIXlt( '2022-01-01 00:00:00', '2022-01-01 00:00:00',format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',tz='UTC')`

Comment: You don't need to account for NAs, they will remain NA on their own (assuming they're NA and not `"NA"`).